# Hibernate Error When Commit session

Tags: java, hibernate

**This is my Code in DAOImpl (Hibernate):**

```
@Transactional
    public void insert(Cage cage) {

        Session session = null;
        Transaction tx = null;

        try{
            session = getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory().openSession();
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            session.saveOrUpdate(cage);
            session.flush();
            session.clear();
            tx.commit();

        }catch(RuntimeException e){
            try{
                tx.rollback();
            }catch(RuntimeException rbe){
                rbe.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("Couldn’t roll back transaction");
            }
            throw e;
        }finally{
            if(session!=null){
                session.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

When for the second time operations data entry (Same PK) takes place with this problem :

> org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update

Comment: You should include the entire stack trace, not the first line.

Comment: primary key should be unique for each entry,second entry with same pk will definitely give that exception.

Comment: no need to flush and clear before commit

Answer (score 1):

As per your question

```
When for the second time operations data entry (Same PK) takes place with this problem : org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException:
```

You are trying to insert same primary key twice.
You cant have same primary key for two entries in database.

Primary keys must contain UNIQUE values.
Check this link
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_primarykey.asp

Keep primary key unique and you wont get this exception.
And if you need duplicate entries for that coloumn then dont make it a primary key

To auto generate id

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="\"ID\"")
private int id;

Comment: primary key is sequence in BO , when I insert  second time operations data entry   takes place with this problem For Same PK